# Maximum product of word lengths in Python

Tags: python, performance

Problems was to calculate [maximum product of word lengths](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-product-of-word-lengths/):

> Given a string array words, find the maximum value of `length(word[i])
>   * length(word[j])` where the two words do not share common letters. You may assume that each word will contain only lower case letters. If
>   no such two words exist, return 0.
>
> ```
> Given ["abcw", "baz", "foo", "bar", "xtfn", "abcdef"]
> Return 16
> The two words can be "abcw", "xtfn".
>
> Example 2:
> Given ["a", "ab", "abc", "d", "cd", "bcd", "abcd"]
> Return 4
> The two words can be "ab", "cd".
>
> Example 3:
> Given ["a", "aa", "aaa", "aaaa"]
> Return 0
> ```

My answer is correct and passed all the test cases. I am looking to get some code review on this.

```py
class Solution(object):
    def maxProduct(self, words):
        """
        maximum value of length(word[i]) * length(word[j]) where the two words do not share common letters
        >> maxProduct(["eae", "ea", "aaf", "bda", "fcf", "dc", "ac", "ce", "cefde", "dabae"])
        >> 15
        """
        max_product = 0
        words = sorted(words, key=len, reverse=True)
        for index, j in enumerate(words):
            for i in words[index + 1:]:
                count = 0
                for k in i:
                    if k in j:
                        count = 1
                        break
                if not count:
                    m = len(j)
                    n = len(i)
                    word_product = m * n
                    if ((m == n) or (m > n and n == m - 1)) and word_product > max_product:
                        return word_product
                    if word_product > max_product:
                        max_product = word_product
        return max_product
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My solution is quite different, let me explain it:

At first I define a small helper to check if two words have any letter in common, it may also be in-lined, but I like small functions.

```
def common(a, b):
    """
    >>> common("hello", "hi")
    {'h'}
    """
    return set(a) & set(b)
```

Then I define the relevant score function for the strings, as you see, after defining our criteria we are almost done.

```
def product_score(w1, w2):
    """
    >>> product_score("foo", "bar")
    9
    >>> product_score("foo", "fuu")
    0
    """
    return 0 if common(w1, w2) else len(w1) * len(w2)
```

The last step is very easy. We already know the criteria, so we can just `map` it over the combination of 2 of the input list and take the `max`:

```
def maxProduct(words):
    """
    Maximum value of length(word[i]) * length(word[j]) where the two words do not share common letters.

    >>> maxProduct(["eae", "ea", "aaf", "bda", "fcf", "dc", "ac", "ce", "cefde", "dabae"])
    15
    """
    return max(product_score(w1, w2) 
                   for (w1, w2) in itertools.combinations(words, 2))
```

I think my solution is more readable, mainly because it uses smaller functions and because it uses already existing wheels (standard library modules).

Comment: I think you want 0 for the common letters case to handle the example.

Comment: The OP processes the words in reverse order by length, which allows early exit when no further improvement is possible. I don't see this feature in your proposed solution.

Comment: @GarethRees  Yes, but he uses N log N time at first for sorting. So the early abort possibility has a cost. Only benchmarking can tell us which solution is more efficient.

Comment: When you say "more efficient", do you mean "faster"?

Comment: @GarethRees yes, I meant run-time efficiency

Comment: When you say "run-time efficiency", do you mean "run-time speed"?

Comment: @GarethRees Yes, precisely.

Comment: In computing, we normally use "efficiency" to mean "algorithmic efficiency" — that is, the rate of use of resources (like space and time) as a function of the input size. Here, the overall algorithm takes time \$O(n^2)\$ (where \$n\$ is the number of words), so the \$O(n \log n)\$ sort makes no difference to the efficiency (but it might make a difference to the speed).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33630/discussion-between-caridorc-and-gareth-rees).

Answer (score 5):

#### Avoid introducing so many variables

We have a ton of variables here: `index`, `i`, `j`, `k`, `m`, and `n`. They're all semi-important, and who knows what they mean. Try to avoid this proliferation. We can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to pairwise iterate to avoid your top two loops:

```
for w1, w2 in itertools.combinations(words, 2):
   ...
```

We can introduce a new function to check that the words are disjoint:

```
def disjoint_words(a, b):
    return not (set(a) & set(b))

for w1, w2 in itertools.combinations(words, 2):
   if disjoint_words(w1, w2):
       ...
```

And then just use `len` when doing the lengths:

```
def maxProduct(words):
    max_product = 0
    words = sorted(words, key=len, reverse=True)
    for w1, w2 in itertools.combinations(words, 2):
       if disjoint_words(w1, w2):
           cur = len(w1) * len(w2)
           if (len(w1) in (len(w2), len(w2) + 1) and
                   cur > max_product):
               return cur
           max_product = max(cur, max_product)
    return max_product
```

This is a lot more manageable.

Comment: What happened to all the comments?

Comment: In addition to there being a lot of variables, they could also be better names (why is `j` the outer loop variable and `i` the inner, which isn't idiomatic in any language community afaik? why does `j` correspond to `m` and `i` to `n`, which swaps the alphabetic order of characters? `i` and `j` are also more commonly used for integer loop variables, and I don't think most people would expect to see them used for strings)